# Add value to object type c#

Tags: c#, object

I've have object like this:

```
object rt = new {
    page = 1,
};
```

Now how could I add new values to this object? I mean something like this:

```
rt += { code = 5 };
```

How it could be possible?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: You can't do that. You have to specify the property at the time of instantiation.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Are you asking for dynamic typing? Are you trying to convert a concept from another language to C#? It wouild be better if you explained what you actually want to do, not how you think it should be done

Comment: For example, dynamic typing in C# is provided by the `dynamic` keyword and the ExpandoObject as shown by @RawitasKrungkaew

Comment: How do you expect `rt` to get a further property, which it doesn´t have when it was created? You can´t change a class´ members once compiled.

Comment: While ive answered, I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos - I think you have an XY Problem - ie, you think this is the way to solve your problem, but its probably something completely different.

Comment: @Jamiec Which is why I´m voting to close that question

Comment: @HimBromBeere whiich is of course your right to do - but I disagree its unclear what theyre asking - its totally clear, but its probably the wrong question :) I wish there was a close reason of "You have an XY Problem" with a link [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Jamiec Hmmm, you´re probably right. I added an answer which shows the whrongness of the question.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks. I didn't know about XY problem. I'll try not ask XY questions in the future. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @user1422847 no problem. Glad we could help. If you describe what youre actually tring to achieve (rather than how youre trying to achieve it) im sure we could guide you better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual question is: why do you need this at all? Imagine your object was a named one, e.g. like this:

```
var m = new MyClass { MyProperty = ... };
```

with

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty;
}
```

What you want to do is, to add a further property to that class at runtime, which isn´t possible. You can´t do the following:

```
m.AnotherProperty = ...
```

as `AnotherProperty` isn´t defined on that type.

Even declaring `m` as `dynamic` wouldn´t help you, as the *actual* type (`MyClass`) doesn´t know anything of `AnotherProperty`.

```
dynamic a = new MyClass { MyProperty = ... };
a.AnotherProperty = ...;
```

So the simple answer to your question is: **no, you can´t add members to a class at runtime.**

Comment: Probably worth noting that the `var x = new {foo=1}` just creates something similar to a class "under the hood". But this is indeed the "right" answer to the question.

Comment: @Jamiec I know. I just wanted to simplify this a bit, as it has nothing to do with anonymous types at all.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds more like you want a `Dictionary<string,int>`

```
var rt =  new Dictinary<string,int>(){
    {"page",1}
};

rt.Add("code",5);
```

You can also do it with `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` - but this is just a fancy wrapper around a dictionary.

```
dynamic rt = new ExpandoObject();
rt.page = 1;
rt.code = 5;

Console.WriteLine(rt.page);
```

Comment: Why dictionary instead of a dynamic type?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just updating with the `dynamic` equivalent.

Answer (score 8):

Use ExpandoObject

```
 dynamic rt = new ExpandoObject();
 rt.page = 1;
 rt.code = 5;
```